# How to remove double slashes from column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have recently found a bug in my website that has been inserting an extra backslash in the URL. I have fixed the bug, but would like to clean up my historical data.

My table name is `visits` and column name is `url`. Some of the example URLs in the field are:

```
www.mysite.com//
www.mysite.com//restaurant/mcdonalds/
www.example.com//
```

How can I do a find and replace on `//` to change it to `/` in MySQL?

I would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
update visits set url=replace(url, '//', '/');
```